# When I click the sign-up button it's not going to the sign up component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

What I'm aiming for is when I click the sign up button is that it would go to the component `SignUp`. But unfortunately it's not routing or functioning.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/App.css";
import Homepage from "./pages/homepage";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
  <Homepage/>
};

export default App;
```

Body.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Link, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "../pages/signUp";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <button type="button" id="signup-btn">
          <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
        </button>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signup" element={SignUp}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Body;
```

Any suggestions? Or should I rewrite my code where navbars are separated?

Answer (score 1):

First, in your App.js file, make sure to import the `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` and wrap the entire application with it:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/App.css";
import Homepage from "./pages/homepage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Now, in your Body.js file, remove the unnecessary `<BrowserRouter>` element since it's already used in App.js.
 Instead, use the `Link` component to navigate to the SignUp component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "../pages/signUp";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="signup-btn">
        <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `HomePage` component in `App` is the `Body` component from the second snippet you've a few things mixed up.

Promote the `BrowserRouter` above the `App` component so it's the sole routing context provider.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

...

<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

From here you have a couple choices:

1. Render `Homepage` on the root `"/"` route with an appended `"*"` wildcard  character so that descendent routes can also be matched and rendered.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import "./styles/App.css";
   import Homepage from "./pages/homepage";
   import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

   export const App = () => {
     return (
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/*" element={<Homepage />} />
       </Routes>
     );
   };

   export default App;
   ```
2. Remove the `Routes` and root `"/"` route from `App` and just render `HomePage` directly.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import "./styles/App.css";
   import Homepage from "./pages/homepage";
   import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

   export const App = () => {
     return <Homepage />;
   };

   export default App;
   ```

The `Switch` is a RRDv5 component and was replaced by the `Routes` component. The `Route` component's `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`, e.g JSX. I suggest also renaming the component from `Body` to `HomePage` so there's no future confusion.

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SignUp from "../pages/signUp";

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="signup-btn">
        <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
      </button>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

> Or should I rewrite my code where navbars are separated?

I think this is a good idea. A refactor may look something like the following:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/App.css";
import Homepage from "./pages/homepage";
import SignUp from "../pages/signUp";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <button type="button" id="signup-btn">
        <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
      </button>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```